# PHP SoapClient, wsdl has required field but is not actually required

Tags: php, .net, soap, wsdl

Ok so another PHP SoapClient question, and you guessed it accessing a .net wsdl.

I am accessing a soap service, that has elements that have min requires of 1, so if you omit these from php SoapClient it throws an error saying the element is not present.

If I do supply them / supply a null value / pass empty value the soap service in question throws an error. The parameter in question is a boolean.

How ever when I send a request via SoapUI with out the parameters in the xml, I get a valid response back.

Also had a friend try this in .net, the object's parameter in question had a default value of null. My friend has told me a sting in .net has a default null value but a boolean does not?

I am confused as to what I should try, currently using the deprecated __call method?

Update:

The section in the wsdl is as follows:

```
<s:complexType name="BankDetails">
    <s:sequence>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="AccountName" type="s:string"/>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="AccountNumber" type="s:string"/>
        <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Amex" type="s:boolean"/>
        <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="ChequeCard" type="s:boolean"/>
        <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="CreditLimit" type="s:decimal"/>
        <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="CurrentAccount" type="s:boolean"/>
        <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="DepositAccount" type="s:boolean"/>
        <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Diners" type="s:boolean"/>
        <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="DirectDebit" type="s:boolean"/>
        <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="JointAccount" type="s:boolean"/>
        <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Mastercard" type="s:boolean"/>
        <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Months" type="s:int"/>
        <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="MortgageAccount" type="s:boolean"/>
        <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="OtherCard" type="s:boolean"/>
        <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="PaymentBookRequired" type="s:boolean"/>
        <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Storecard" type="s:boolean"/>
        <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Visa" type="s:boolean"/>
        <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Years" type="s:int"/>
    </s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
```

The request that was successful I sent in Soap UI was:

```
<BankDetails>
    <CurrentAccount>true</CurrentAccount>
    <Months>0</Months>
    <Years>3</Years>
</BankDetails>
```

Comment: I have the exact same issue. Did you every resolve this? Removing the element gives me an error that it is not present. But omitting it in SoapUI works fine.

Comment: No, sorry. I did take a quick look at the code, I am not sure what this relates to anymore. .Net soap stuff just sucks most of the time. Have you tried using a php wsdl code generator?

Comment: I managed to eventually get it to work by specifying the elements but just passing empty strings, zeros for int, false for boolean.. everything working now, but I would really like to know why SoapUI can leave out those elements and I cant.. very strange.. but thanks man :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're passing XML, try removing the whole element that's empty.  For instance if it's breaking on  because you have it empty just remove that whole line.  Most WSDLs don't like to receive a line that is empty.  They would either rather have something inside it, or not have that line at all.

Alternatively try passing a false boolean.

Comment: We have tried most combinations, however it seems if you do pass some fields then it expects others.

If the element is not there SoapClient will error and not send the request.

Comment: Would have to see your documentation to really figure it out.  Sounds like you could have some dependencies that are really the root of the issue here.